# How to optimized this union query

Tags: mysql

I have three MySQL tables.  `PRODUCT` is a parent with two children, `UK_SALES` and `AUS_SALES`.  The structure of `UK_SALES` and `AUS_SALES` is identical, and they are related to `PRODUCT` via a product id.

I want to get the union of sales in UK and AUS for a given category of product, so I am using this query:

```
SELECT au.* FROM aus_sales au
INNER JOIN product p on p.id = au.id
WHERE p.category = 'electrical'

UNION ALL

SELECT uk.* FROM uk_sales uk
INNER JOIN product p on p.id = uk.id
WHERE p.category = 'electrical'
```

Now, that works fine however I'm not sure it's optimal.  Specifically, I think that the product table is scanned twice to restrict it to

`WHERE p.category = 'electrical'`.

Is this really the case?  Or will MySQL cache the result of the first filter for use in the second select?

Secondly, is there a better way to write this query?

My product and sales tables will both run into millions of records so performance will be important.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there duplicates across the 2 tables? I suppose not, so use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: About the only thing I can see that would help is an index on product.category. This sort of thing is the penalty you pay for splitting the sales table.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are no duplicates across the two tables (UK and AU sales) and if there are, it's just coincidence and you need them both, so use `UNION ALL` to avoid the sorting (and the removal of any duplicates):

```
SELECT au.* FROM aus_sales au
INNER JOIN product p on p.id = au.id
WHERE p.category = 'electrical'

UNION ALL

SELECT uk.* FROM uk_sales uk
INNER JOIN product p on p.id = uk.id
WHERE p.category = 'electrical' ;
```

An index on `product (category, id)` would also help the execution plan as it will be used for both subqueries and the `product` will not be accessed at all.

Comment: Thanks ypercube, I changed UNION to UNION ALL in the original question.  That improves the question, but doesn't really answer it though.  Will the products table need to be filtered twice to apply the WHERE clause?  And is there a better way to write the query?

Comment: Do you really have a need for a query that will return millions of rows? If yes, you should profile and test. Different versions of MySQL may perform different. I'm not really sure about your other question, so I can't answer (if it will be doubling the reading from the product table, actually from only the index - or caching it).